# How to remap tf publication of AMCL

Tags: ros-melodic, amcl, remapping, tf

I'm trying to perform Localization in outdoor and indoor situations, and I would like to remap the /tf publisher from AMCL node so I can redirect it to a mux where I could select which algorithm transform should I use.

If I'm not wrong, using the remap tag would also affect not the publisher but also the subscriber, and I can't do that since AMCL needs the transform from the laser_frame to odom.

I thought this idea because I haven't seen any way to stop AMCL from publishing, without exiting the node.

Could I do this somehow? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `navigation` AMCL implementation, consider using the `tf_broadcast` param.

It controls whether the broadcast happens or not and it supports [dynamic reconfigure](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/9ad644198e132d0e950579a3bc72c29da46e60b0/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L590), which makes it possible to update the param on-the-fly.

Comment: Hello Dimitry, and thanks for the answer. That's good to know, I was expecting somehow a dynamic reconfigure setup in AMCL package, and I was stunned that there wan't, but didn't take into account that it could be done in `navigation`. At the moment I'm not using it, but I might, which in that case, it could be done with this.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry's solution should work, but it seems cleaner to me if you make the mux responsible for publishing the `map->odom` transform, and disable this feature in the amcl node. The mux would subscribe to the robot's pose published by amcl node.

Comment: Hello Mike, thank you for the answer. Your approach was my first suggestion. I thought that the main focus of AMCL node was to publish the tf in order to do the localization, but from your answer I can tell that I could still count with the published amcl_pose msg in order to "create" the tf stimated by AMCL, right? I'll get into this and see if I get it to work!